# stand alone broadcast receiver for Download Manager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which listens for a download complete action so it opens a file when download completes.

My issue with this is that the user may download a file and then minimize the screen which then unregisters the `BroadcastReceiver`, so the file isn't opened automatically when download completes.

How can I set up a stand alone `BroadcastReceiver` so that the image is opened even when the app is stopped/destroyed. I can't figure out how to make it listen to a download complete action.

```
private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        if (downloadReference == referenceId) {
            DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
            query.setFilterById(referenceId);
            Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    Intent intentpic = new Intent();
                    intentpic.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intentpic.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir("/update/asd.jpg")), "image/*");
                    startActivity(intentpic);
                    if(receiverRegistered) {
                        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(downloadReceiver);
                    }
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
            Log.i(TAG, "Downloading of data just finished");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: just call `DownloadManage#query(DownloadManager.Query query)` when your app starts and you will know what has been downloaded so far

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't start activities when your app is in background. It is okay that your receiver is unregistered when user leaves the app.

Instead, store the information that the image is downloaded and then check it when the app is resumed. I don't know your use case, but, for example you can store this information to `SharedPreferences` and check it when the app is resumed. Then you can decide whether to start a new activity or not.